# How to get friend's mobile number using Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How do I get the mobile number of a friend using the REST Api?

I have HTC Sense on my HTC Legend phone, and somehow they can grab the phone numbers from FB, as I got a list of contacts with mobile and birthday taken from FB. I am wondering how they did it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API won't give out mobile numbers - it's too much of a privacy/spam risk.

Comment: Can't we push a phone number to API, and receive back a boolean flag if that matches with the stored one on the profile?

Comment: Nope - Facebook doesn't expose mobile information in any way. I'm actually glad of that.

Comment: I have HTC Sense on my HTC Legend phone, and somehow they can grab the phone numbers from FB, as I got a list of contacts with mobile and birthday taken from FB. I am wondering how they did it?

Comment: They're likely matching other fields, like email address